# The Link Field module is not creating outbound links

Tags: navigation

The [Link module](http://drupal.org/project/link) is not creating external links. I put **'myurl.com'** into the node field  and the rendered a href is `mysite/myurl.com`. The title is being rendered correctly, but the links are relative.

The project page for the Link module says that I should be getting these results of which I was hoping for the second one.

```
http://drupal.org => http://drupal.org
drupal.org => http://drupal.org
<front> => http://drupal.org
node/74971 => http://drupal.org/project/link
```

Did I miss something in the configuration?

Comment: i got the same problem, still struggling with it. hope someone can help me solve it. i thought it is purely a link module bug at this time.

Comment: Which version are you using? According to http://drupal.org/node/1043348, it should be fixed in the latest 7.x-1.x-dev version.